# How can i see the xml Drawerlayout file on android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-fragments

I am creating the XML drawer layout file on android studio but can not previews on android studio am getting this error how can i solve the problem

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#fff"/>
```

I get this error :

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:android.support.v4.widget.Drawer Layout (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem is that you're probably using a lower minSdkVersion. I had the same problem, I had set the minSdkVersion to 14, change it to 17 (in the build.gradle) and it renders correctly.

or it can be   Android Support Library problem

Steps

Right click on Project-> Android Tools->Add Support library.

then I just cleaned the project and I worked for me...

And Obviously Check the Android Library and other Libarary...

Comment: I fail to understand why I have to increase the `minSdkVersion` if part of the point in using `android.support` is to provide backwards support...